# How do I select values from Kendo Grid cells?

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

I need to capture the VALUE that the user enters in the following fields:

- isOnBallot
- concatenationString

The comments in the code below show where I want to use these variables.

The only thing I don't know how to do here is how to reference the VALUE in these two fields. I don't know if there's a specific way I'm supposed to do this with Kendo or try to use jquery.

For example, if I inspect the element concatenationString, this is what I see:

```
<input type="text" class="k-input k-textbox" name="concatenation" data-bind="value:concatenation">
```

Here's the grid definition:

```
function directorsOrRecipients(e)
{
    $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
        reorderable: true,
        resizable: true,
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "http://localhost/x/api/Awards/directors/" + e.data.AwardTitleId,
                    type: "GET"
                },
                create: {
                    url: "http://localhost/x/api/awards/directors",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        awardTitleId: e.data.AwardTitleId,
                        personId: localStorage.personId,
                        nameId: localStorage.nameId,
                        isOnBallot: "True",//I need to get this value based on the user input.,
                        concatenationString: "test1",//I need to get this value based on the user input.
                        whoEntered: 0
                    }
                }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "namefirstlast",
                    fields: {
                        "namefirstlast": { editable: true, type: "string" },
                        "directorsequence": { editable: true, type: "number", validation: { min: 1 } },
                        "isonballot": { editable: true, type: "boolean" },
                        "concatenation": { editable: true, type: "string" },
                        "MoreNames": {
                            editable: true,
                            type: "number",
                            validation: { min: 0 }
                        },
                    },
                },
            }
        },
        columns: [
            { field: "namefirstlast", title: "Name", editor: namesAutoComplete },
            { field: "directorsequence", title: "Director Sequence", format: "{0:n0}" },
            { field: "isonballot", title: "On ballot?" },
            { field: "concatenation", title: "Concatenation" },
            { field: "MoreNames", title: "More names?", format: "{0:n0}" },
            { command: ["edit"], title: "&nbsp;", width: 100 }],
        sortable: true,
        sort: { field: "namefirstlast", dir: "desc" },
        editable: "inline",
        toolbar: [{
            name: "create",
            text: "Add New Director/Recipient"
        }]
    });
}
```

Anyone can give me a hand?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, finally.

You get the values from the cells in which you are inline editing by doing so:

```
save: function(a)
{
   var value = a.model.Item;
}
```

Here's the whole code:

```
save: function(a)
        {
            directorData["Operation"] = "I";

            if (!a.model.isNew())
            {
                directorData["AwardTitleId"] = awardTitleId;
                directorData["PersonId"] = a.model.PersonId;
                directorData["NameId"] = a.model.NameId;
                directorData["Operation"] = "U";
            }

            if (a.model.IsOnBallot == true)
            {
                ballot = 1;
            }

            if (a.model.IsOnBallot == false)
            {
                ballot = 0;
            }

            directorData["DirectorSequence"] = a.model.DirectorSequence;
            directorData["IsOnBallot"] = ballot;
            directorData["Concatenation"] = a.model.Concatenation;

            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost/Take3/api/awards/directors",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: directorData
            }).done(function()
            {
                detailRow.find(".directorsOrRecipients").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
                detailRow.find(".directorsOrRecipients").data("kendoGrid").refresh();

            });
        },
```